# Python : Error: AttributeError: Simulation instance has no attribute 't_arrival'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to python. Can someone point what is wrong with the code? I encounter this error

```
s.clock Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-164-1b826b584407>", line 1, in <module>
s.clock        
AttributeError: Simulation instance has no attribute 'clock'       
s.t_arrival Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<ipython-input-166-d1ae41af4a1e>", line 1, in <module>
s.t_arrival
AttributeError: Simulation instance has no attribute 't_arrival'
```

here is the code :

```
import numpy as np

class Simulation:
    def _init_(self):
        self.num_in_system = 0

        self.clock = 0.0
        self.t_arrival = self.generate_interarrival()
        self.t_depart = float('inf')

        self.num_arrivals = 0
        self.num_departs = 0
        self.total_wait = 0.0




   def advance_time(self):
       pass
   def handle_arrival_event(self):
       pass
   def handle_depart_event(self):
       pass


   def generate_interarrival(self):
       return np.random.exponential(1./3)

   def generate_service(self):
       return np.random.exponential(1./5)  
np.random.seed(0)
s= Simulation()
```

Comment: Maybe you meant to use `__init__` instead of `_init_`?

Comment: Goshhhh.. you are correct! @James Rettie .